# Return Json object to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, python-3.x, flask

I'm developing a web app where I need to update the configuration of a certain type of graph. To do so, I'm using Python3 with flask and html.

I want to update the configuration dynamically, which means that I don't want to use the function `render_template` and instead, I want to use `return jsonify(message)` .

Below I included the function that I want to use to update the data. This function is used as a callback on the rest of my system and those prints are being executed well, which means that on the flask side, everything seems to be okay. However, I don't know what I should put on the html side to receive this data.
Here is the code that I'm using in flask to **send the data**:

```
@app.route('/online_visualization_update')
def online_visualization_update(msg):
    print("I should change the network.")
    print("The message was ", msg)
    with app.app_context():
        return jsonify(msg.transition, msg.marking)
```

This is the code I tried to implement on html to **receive** the data sent by flask:

```
<script type=text/javascript>

fetch('/online_visualization_update')
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(data => console.log(data))
         .catch((error) => {console.error('Error:', error);
});

</script>
```

Currently, this is not working because the the fetch is being performed every time I open the webapp. What am I doing wrong?

Ideally, I would like to have a function on javascript that is executed only when it receives the data from flask but I don't know whether fetch works like that or not.

Thank you

Comment: You'd need `fetch("/online_visualization_update").then(res => res.json()).then(obj => {...});` (note that what the server sends is JSON, and after parsing, it becomes an Object; there's no such thing as a "JSON object")

Comment: I want the code on flask to be executed first and the fetch second. I think that fetch works the other way around maybe. I updated my original question.

Comment: The point of `fetch()` (or more generally: AJAX) is to communicate with the server in the background, without leaving the current page. This communication is initiated on the client. If you are looking for a way to initiate communication on the server, you need to use sockets instead, that way if something happens on the server, you can update the clients. Note that this is significantly more work to implement, so if it's enough to update the client every 30 seconds or so, just put the fetch call in a `setInterval` function.

Comment: The main problem here is that this is a perfect example of an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/); you're asking about JSON and fetch but your actual question is about something completely different: updationg the client after a server event. Take a step back and describe the goal and context.

Comment: I think that the setInterval idea might work well. How can I implement it? And you are right, I thought this was a very simple issue that could be solved almost immediately but it turns out that it involves more concepts than I initially thought.

Comment: Just wrap the fetch call in `setInterval(function() {` and `}, 30 * 1000);`, this will run it every 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to use Fetch API in javascript like this

```
  // write function like this
  function callApi(){
    fetch('/online_visualization_update')
     .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
   }
```

Refer this for more about fetch:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Add this code in your Html page:

```
   <Div class="container">
            <button type="button" onclick="callApi()">Call func</button>
            <!--you need to call function like this whenever you need data -->
    </Div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Just another question: what should I put on the part that says "hello"? Because the message that I'm sending is not always the same.

Comment: @PedroCaldeira this is just an example. you can pass any parameter.

Comment: My goal is to send from flask to javascript. I don't want to send from javascript to flask. How do I fetch only when I send the data from flask? At the moment, the javscript is being executed immediately after I open the web app, instead of waiting for the data to be sent from flask.

Comment: ok.For that you need to write function in javascript & call them whenever you want.

Comment: I have the flask part (which I included in the original question) and I have the javascript code just like you posted. But it's still being called every time I open the webapp, instead of being called when I return jsonify(msg.transition, msg.marking). Maybe fetch doesn't allow me to do what I want.

Comment: for this you need to write function & call that function from your html page.check my  answer.updated now. & also to return data from jsonify  need to send like this
 return jsonify(transition=transition_var marking=mark_var)

Comment: Your answer would work but ideally, I would like to have a system without any buttons, so that my graph (my web app is a graph visualization tool) is updated periodically and not with a push of a button.

Comment: now issue is of your python code. 
1.what data contain msg variable?  
2.why you added parameter as msg?
3.what is the path of server like this you need to add in url 
 when fetch api calls http://127.0.0.1:5000/online_visualization_update

that's why it is not working.